# When using conditional types for the return of a function, how to get type awareness on each return in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

See the code below. As I am doing the `switch (pageName)`, I was expecting TS to be aware of what should be returned in each case. How can I achieve that?

[TypeScript Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACghgcwgOTgW2gXigcjIiAQRygB9d8kAhHAbgChHRJYCYAnAezAGcAeACpQIAD2AQAdgBMerJKgwA+KNnpQoQ0eOmy8BYlAD8UAN5QAZp06EAXLgBGcdsQC+UG2o3CxkmRQI0RmaWnFR2OI7sNG4e6hIQAG4Q7PQM6upM4NAA4hDA8EgAInDAcCpQgt7afgUo6BCKABSUdRh2AgCUKsocnGgAljwQfLW9vIKKigz0omCc7MBQAMacEjyLSPkExaV2uVtFJWXYcDwgEktQzQQKEF2Yyiae6jwA7v3ASwAWVy23XU90kDlqdoHokAZAcDoew8gBXdgSUzPaGolGoqAudHpLEYpag-zUEhQjHqWHABFIkmkoHY6G41EM9RMqDkykMFxAA)

```
type PageName = 'pageA' | 'pageB';


type PageProps<T extends PageName> = 
  T extends 'pageA' ? { fooA: 'barA'} :
  T extends 'pageB' ?{ fooB: 'barB'} :
  never
;
    

type GetPageData = <T extends PageName>(pageName: T) => Promise<PageProps<T>>;

export const getPageData: GetPageData = async (pageName) => {
    switch (pageName) {
        case 'pageA' {
            return {
                
            }
        }
        case 'pageB' {
            return {
                
            }
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

**Screenshot version:**

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Please post code, error messages, markup, data structures, and other textual information **as text**, not just as a *picture* of text. Why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247 (It's not my downvote but people **really** don't like pictures of code.)

Comment: Even though the code is also in the TypeScript playground, your whole question (including any necessary code) has to be **in** your question, not just linked. Three reasons: People shouldn't have to go off-site to help you; some sites are blocked for some users; and links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future. Please put a [mcve] **in** the question. More: [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: It would be simpler using a function overload. Is that an option for what you're doing?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder , yeah, I can try that. Thanks. But it's weird that TS is not picking that up. Because it know what the function returns if you call it, like `const pageAProps = getPageData('pageA');`. It knows that `pageAprops` is of the correct type. Not sure why it's not doing the same inside the function's body.

Comment: I'm not sure either, but I'm a bit distracting at the moment. Overloads FWIW: https://tsplay.dev/wQx91W

Comment: \* distract**ed**

Comment: Thanks! I decided to do type assertions on my returns for now.

Comment: You should not use generics for conditional return types.

Comment: @caTS what should I use then?

Comment: Overloads, of course, as TJ has demonstrated. Generics don't work quite as well. Let's say your function is `<T extends A | B>(a: T): T extends A ? string : number`. Well, that means `T` could potentially be `A | B`... It's not *limited* to just `A` or just `B`, unlike overloads, where it can only be `A` or `B` if you defined it like that, but not `A | B`.

Comment: @caTS thanks! Yeah, I was really trying to avoid overloads. I usually don't have a good dev-X with them. Also, my real use-case is a bit more complex than the example. I decided to just split it into multiple functions. Thanks everyone